# IllegalArgumentException while creating/opening a directory on external storage

Tags: android, file, illegalargumentexception

i've occured an illegal argument exception in this portion of code:

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    full_path = root+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) ;
    File dir_path = getApplicationContext().getDir(full_path, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

this is the error log:

```
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.streamfilesys/com.example.streamfilesys.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File app_/storage/emulated/0/StreamFileSys contains a path separator
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File app_/storage/emulated/0/StreamFileSys contains a path separator
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1966)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getDir(ContextImpl.java:1816)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDir(ContextWrapper.java:218)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at com.example.streamfilesys.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-08 12:26:23.717: E/AndroidRuntime(9234):     ... 11 more
```

the mainActivity line 39 is

```
File dir_path = getApplicationContext().getDir(full_path, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: i think you forget to put path separator "/"

Comment: Try    File dir_path =  getActivity().getFileStreamPath(full_path);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as doc says about [Context.getDir (String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) :

> Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application
>   can place its own custom data files. You can use the returned File
>   object to create and access files in this directory. Note that files
>   created through a File object will only be accessible by your own
>   application; you can only set the mode of the entire directory, not of
>   individual files.

means instead of passing file name with file separator u will need to pass only folder(Dir) name as first paramter to getDir methods as ":

```
File dir_path = getApplicationContext().getDir(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**EDIT:**

to create Dir on external SDCARD. change your code as :

```
File onsdcarddir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                               "/" +getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

if (!onsdcarddir.exists()) {
   onsdcarddir.mkdir(); // create dir here
}
```

also add SDCARD permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: but i need to write directory and data on external storage. How the sistem knows that i want to create folder on external storage if i use your code?

Comment: i've already try the code with mkdir() function, but it doesn't admit to specify mode about folder like getDir. i need also to set mode!

Comment: @giozh : not possible to changes permission on SDCARD for any file or folder